# Why does my function while loop go from 5,4,3,2,1 in console but 1,2,3,4,5 in the web page

Tags: javascript

So, i have this js code:

```
function lFunc(){

    var loopCount = 5;

    while(loopCount > 0) {

        var target = document.getElementById("p3");
        target.innerHTML = "loopcount: " + loopCount + "<br>" + target.innerHTML;
        console.log("loopcount is now: " + loopCount);
        loopCount = loopCount - 1;
    }
}
```

in the console it shows:

```
loopcount is now: 5
loopcount is now: 4
loopcount is now: 3
loopcount is now: 2
loopcount is now: 1
```

but in the web page it shows:

```
loopcount: 1
loopcount: 2
loopcount: 3
loopcount: 4
loopcount: 5
```

The target var reference is just an empty open and closed p tag.
I don't understand why the webpage goes from 1 to 5, in my mind it should go from 5 to 1

Comment: Because you are adding in the front. So first it says "loop count 5". Then you add "loop count 4" in the front. And so on

Comment: what do you think `"loopcount: " + loopCount + "<br>" + target.innerHTML` does

Comment: Because `console.log` appends messages in the end, but your `innerHTML` modification does prepend it.

Answer (score 2):

Your concatenation is messed up here:

```
target.innerHTML = "loopcount: " + loopCount + "<br>" + target.innerHTML;
```

Eg, if the existing HTML is 5, and you prepend it with 4, the resulting HTML will be `4 5`. Use `+=` instead, so that later iterations add markup to the *end* of the container, rather than prepending it to the beginning:

```
target.innerHTML += "loopcount: " + loopCount + "<br>";
```

Or, to avoid having to re-parse all the existing markup in the container on every iteration, use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead:

```
target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "loopcount: " + loopCount + "<br>");
```

Or insert `<div>`s instead of `<br>`s:

```
target.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent = 'loopcount: ' + loopCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the desired output to match your console output, you will need to reverse the DOM output.  The code would look like:

```
 function lFunc() {

    var loopCount = 5;

    while(loopCount > 0) {

        var target = document.getElementById("p3");
        target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML + "<br />loopcount: " + loopCount;
        console.log("loopcount is now: " + loopCount);
        loopCount = loopCount - 1;
    }
 }
```

which outputs:

```
loopcount: 5
loopcount: 4
loopcount: 3
loopcount: 2
loopcount: 1
```

What you originally had during execution time would look like this:

```
target.innerHTML = "LoopCount: " + loopCount + "<br>" + "LoopCount: 5<br>";
//where your "LoopCount: 5<br>" is the value of target.innerHTML
```

the result would be:

```
LoopCount: 1<br>LoopCount: 2<br>LoopCount: 3<br>LoopCount: 3<br>LoopCount: 5<br>
```

which outputs:

```
loopcount: 1
loopcount: 2
loopcount: 3
loopcount: 4
loopcount: 5
```